# Cannot 'trust project' or 'synic' my gradle file in my android studio

Tags: android, project, trust

I'm a student who just starting writing my own app this semester, and this issue came out a few days ago.
Those pop out message from the application is unclickable. Not just in this project, but all projects.

[nothing happened after clicking "Trust project"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uA6iW.png)

I can't even create new project.

[it never stop loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAkHT.png)

Comment: Probably https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-284642

What version of the IDE do you have? Try upgrading to the latest 2022.1.3, or at least to 2021.3.2 where the abovementioned bug was fixed. Possible workaround: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-286682/Unable-to-trust-project#focus=Comments-27-5710109.0-0

Answer (score 0):

It may be caused by a bug.

Check `trusted-paths.xml` to see if you have contained the project's parent folder to the setting and set the value to the `false`. If the entry is set to `false`, it means Android Studio doesn't trust this folder and all of the children folders. It won't work even you have trust the children folder.

The file path is:

`~/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio<CHANGE_IT_TO_THE_REAL_VERSION>/options/trusted-paths.xml`

As for now, this bug still exists in the latest version built on July 10 (2022.2.1 Patch2).

Comment: Thanks @Koyasha 's comment to the question, I write this answer to help others find `trusted-paths.xml` path easier.